# Is it acceptable to announce Area51 site in chat rooms?

Tags: discussion, chat, area-51

I just have created [Scientific Imagination](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination?referrer=IPIEcsN2huMFuP7v0aO_3g2) on Area51, and looking to get followers for the proposal.

I think I will have interested people on technology oriented Stack Exchange sites. And the problem is, I don't know a canonical way to reach them.

If I were to post a minimal message to chat rooms, would that be considered spam?

Comment: @iStimple: Yeah :) That's why I started the proposal. You can support it if you like. You can follow the proposal, vote some questions and even post some questions.

Comment: What about announcing in on the Metas of appropriate sites?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Well, [I asked a question on StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269820/is-it-acceptable-to-announce-area51-proposal), but it did not go well. :D But you're right. I think users of technology-oriented sites will _love_ this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't just barge into all rooms with same message "Please follow my proposal", that won't end well.

Best if you start in rooms you're already familiar with, with people who know you and see how they respond.

If you enter a room you never visited before, start by introducing yourself and wait a bit before throwing the link at them.

Other than that, chat should be relaxed enough to allow those things, just don't push it too much, and don't expect horde of users to come and follow the proposal.