# Android App sometimes loads all comments on a question as identical

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

I'm not sure exactly what this bug requires, but I've been able to reliably reproduce it in the question [Is it acceptable to announce Area51 site in chat rooms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238605/is-it-acceptable-to-announce-area51-site-in-chat-rooms)

I suspect it's reproducible only on questions with a *small number* of comments (4 in this case) such that the "X more comments" thing never shows up, because I haven't been able to reproduce it on questions with a large number of comments. It *also* requires a link to another Stack Exchange question.

This occurs in Android App v1.0.48 on a HTC One running Android 4.4.2.

Here's the bug and how to reproduce it. You can click the images for the full view.

## 1. Find a link in comments

This must be a link to another question, which the Stack Exchange app itself will handle.

Try the link in the last comment in [Is it acceptable to announce Area51 site in chat rooms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238605/is-it-acceptable-to-announce-area51-site-in-chat-rooms)

> [image]

## 2. Tap the link, let the new question load, hit the Back button.

That's your Android phone's back button. There's nothing wrong with the question we visit. But when we return... the comments look like this.

> [image]

That's it. This is really weird.

Comment: Wow, repro'd on my device. *Awesome* find!

Comment: I flagged this as "cannot be repro'd" since the current version now shows Q&A on a single thread. Also, the comment section has been revamped slightly (looks different than current version)... and I couldn't repro the issue on the latest version (1.0.77/1.0.82 beta) too.

Comment: @AndrewT Yeah, this is way old and I haven't seen it happen ever recently.